# Configurar sublime REPL para que ejecute el código con Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sublimetext3

Mi problema es que no se como decirle a SublimeText al momento de instalar el paquete `sublimeREPL` que se instale en Python 3 y no en Python 2 ya que este ultimo viene instalado por defecto en linux pero quiero usar la version 3 para programar.

Me he leído infinitos posts y no he encontrado una solución.

Me hice un nuevo build donde puedo ejecutar mis códigos con Python 3, le digo que imprima la versión con la que esta trabajando y efectivamente es python 3.5 pero cuando ejecuto el mismo código desde sublime REPL me imprime que trabaja con python 2.7

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Espero su pronta respuesta y disculpen mi ignorancia.

Uso linux mint 18 sarah.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que ya creaste un Build System que ejecuta Python 3 pero te hace falta configurar SublimeREPL para hacer lo mismo. Yo utilizo mac pero imagino que el proceso puede ser el mismo.

Lo que tienes que hacer es buscar el archivo Main.sublime-menu en "Sublime Text 3 -> Packages -> SublimeREPL -> config -> Python" y cambiar el código que contiene por el siguiente:

```
[
 {
    "id": "tools",
    "children":
    [{
        "caption": "SublimeREPL",
        "mnemonic": "r",
        "id": "SublimeREPL",
        "children":
        [
            {"caption": "Python",
            "id": "Python",

             "children":[
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python",
                 "id": "repl_python",
                 "mnemonic": "p",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                    }
                },
                {"command": "python_virtualenv_repl",
                 "id": "python_virtualenv_repl",
                 "caption": "Python - virtualenv"},
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python - PDB current file",
                 "id": "repl_python_pdb",
                 "mnemonic": "d",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "-m", "pdb", "$file_basename"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                    }
                },
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
                 "id": "repl_python_run",
                 "mnemonic": "d",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file_basename"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                    }
                },
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python - IPython",
                 "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                 "mnemonic": "p",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "autocomplete_server": true,
                    "cmd": {
                        "osx": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                        "linux": ["python3", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                        "windows": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"]
                    },
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {
                        "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                        "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                    }
                }
                }
            ]}
        ]
    }]
}]
```

si aún tienes problemas quizas este video te pueda ayudar:

[Tutorial configuración SublimeREPL para ejecutar Python 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KriWsYvLyRg&t=2s)

Espero que mi respuesta te hay a sido útil, suerte
Saludos

Comment: ya cree el Build System que ejecuta Python 3 { "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"], "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)", "selector": "source.python" } y guarde el código que dices en Main.sublime-menu. Todo bien, pero solo hay un detalle y es que al ejecutar el código al final ya no sale el tiempo que le toma ejecutarlo sino sale ">>>" y o se porque. [![ejecución en python3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywpDX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywpDX.png)