# NO PUEDO EJECUTAR PYTHON 3 EN SUBLIME TEXT

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x, sublimetext

veran amigos no puedo ejecutar python3 desde el sublime text ya que en vez de hacerlo,ejecuta python 2,7 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo lo abres? Danos más datos que una captura de pantalla para que al menos podamos elucubrar soluciones

Comment: Hola heart, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Deberías agregar más información como comenta fedorqui. (Cómo ejecutas el script, si has configurado REPL y cómo, si tienes instalado Python 3 y agregado al PATH y con que comando (p.e `python3`)). De cualquier forma, la pregunta es un posible  duplicado de [Configurar sublime REPL para que ejecute el código con Python 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/168439/15089). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Asegurate que el PATH o dirección de la ubicación de python 3 este tanto en las variables de sistema como en la configuración de compilador de sublime.